# Xamarin TapGestureRecognizer tap event fired on background taps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was faced with some weird behavior of ***TapGestureRecognizer***. I have some simple Xamarin page like below

```
<StackLayout>
    <Path
        ClassId="BottomCone"
        Fill="{AppThemeBinding Dark=#333333, Light=#444444}"
        Data="{x:Static local:MainPage.BottomConeGeometry}"
        BackgroundColor="Red"
                
    >
        <Path.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BottomConeTapped" />
        </Path.GestureRecognizers>
    </Path>
</StackLayout>
```

Though it's actually just some simple closed shape drown with ***Path*** element on which I have some handler of tap event. And the problem is that event is firing every time when I'm clicking on Path or its background. Is it possible to not fire the tap event when the tap happened in the background of the path? And fire the event just in case the tap event happened inside a Path element.

Comment: I don't see any support for this, anywhere in Xamarin Forms. For that matter, I don't see it in Android (when not using Xamarin), so it isn't surprising that Xamarin does not support it. The simplest hack I can think of is to manually define a circle (or ellipse) that approximates the path shape. Then when get click event, do your own math to determine whether it is inside that circle. Or more generally, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon.

Comment: Touch is generally considered an "approximate" user action. That is, we want to know what user's intention is, not necessarily whether they exactly fit their finger inside a given shape. Say more about your design goal, that leads you to care whether the touch is inside the visible shape, as opposed to within the rectangle enclosing the shape.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I believe it's totally fine to have multiple buttons on the same screen that you can touch. What's wrong with that? And when you have a button I believe you want to know whether the user clicked on a button or somewhere outside the button right? My purpose is the same the only difference is that my buttons have different forms described with Path shapes. And it's a shame that we are not able to distinguish whether the user touched the button or someplace outside it.

Comment: Huh? My point is that generally one wants to know **which** button someone pressed, not whether they managed to touch exactly the pixels that match the button's shape. You haven't explained why it matters to your app. If the user touches the screen approximately in the area of the button, the most likely intention is "I'm trying to touch this button". Don't make it any harder than necessary.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve right it works when you have standard formed buttons. But when you have a relative layout for non-standard buttons that are close to each other it happened that backgrounds overlay each other but not the drawn buttons itself and when you are pressing one button you are getting Handler from another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the shapes have overlapping "bounds" (the rectangle surrounding each shape).

One technique is to have a set of rectangles that approximates each of the shapes. The concept is to make the shapes themselves `InputTransparent`, and have an overlapping set of invisible boxes that capture touch.

OverlappingShapeButtonsPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XFSOAnswers.OverlappingShapeButtonsPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="BoxView">
            <!-- Uncomment, to see where OnTapped1 boxes are. -->
            <!--<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>-->
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>

            <AbsoluteLayout InputTransparent="True">
                <Polygon Points="0,0 80,0 0,60" Fill="Green" />
                <Polygon Points="80,0 80,60 0,60" Fill="Pink" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>

            <Grid RowDefinitions="20,20,20" ColumnDefinitions="20,20,20,20"
                  RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped2" />
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                    <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped1" />
                    </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                </BoxView>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped1" />
                    </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                </BoxView>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                    <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped1" />
                    </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                </BoxView>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

OverlappingShapeButtonsPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XFSOAnswers
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class OverlappingShapeButtonsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public OverlappingShapeButtonsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when any of the BoxViews are touched.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void OnTapped1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the grid is touched anywhere that is not inside one of the BoxViews.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void OnTapped2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What user sees:
[image]

Red showing boxes for OnTapped1, approximating Green triangle:
[image]

This works reasonably well, because user will tend to touch near the center of the shape they are interested in.

---

You could refine this by doing simple (x,y) math calculations that approximate the edge between two shapes.

---

In General, Make sure that you aren't expecting unrealistic precision from user's touch. Primarily, that means that the touch areas should not be too small (more than one in a small area).

Consider these (or similar) guidelines: [Optimal Size and Spacing for Mobile Touch](https://uxmovement.com/mobile/optimal-size-and-spacing-for-mobile-buttons/).